# Github - Take check status and update commit status

Tags: github-actions, aws-amplify, netlify-cms

**Simplifying Question:**
How do I make a github action that will take a specific checkstatus for a commit (pull) and update the commit status of that pull?
(These being two different APIs).

--

ADDITIONAL INFO IF YOU WOULD LIKE:

--

**Situation:**

1. Sites building on amplify.
2. Code in Repo in Github.
3. Would like to use NetlifyCMS as CMS.
4. Netlify CMS looks for github commit status on PRs for previewlinks (I'm pretty sure at least: https://github.com/netlify/netlify-cms/issues/5161 <- not my thread but good reference I believe.
5. Amplify does it's work on the github checks API.

And therefore preview links do not work.

**Problem:**

How do I get this pieces glued together?

**Possible solutions:**

1. A Github Action that takes the checks API status and updates the commit status.
   or
2. Amplify set-up to update commit stats on PR as well
   or
3. Netlify CMS changed to check github checks <- I believe this is the worst idea of the 3.

**Request for guidance:**

If 1 or 2 are valid solutions, could someone review and give any experience/guidance/working basics I Can start with?

Comment: You'll want https://stackoverflow.com/a/72642838/1757964.