# How to associate status of a Github action workflow with a commit or PR

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a Github action workflow which is set to trigger on `issue_comment`, for example the following

```yaml
name: Testing actions
on:
  issue_comment:
    types: [created, edited]

jobs:
  testing-actions:
    if: github.event.issue.pull_request && contains(github.event.comment.body, '@test')
    name: Just testing
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: xt0rted/pull-request-comment-branch@v1
        id: comment-branch
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          ref: ${{ steps.comment-branch.outputs.head_ref }}
      - name: Print stuff
        run: echo "Hello dudes!"
```

The workflow is working, it is getting triggered when I comment "@test" on a PR. But I have to check it from the *actions* tab, the workflow doesn't get associated with any commit or PR, so it doesn't get shown in the checks tab in the PR, or the commits don't show any commit status.

How do I get the workflow status and details in the PR page, so that I don't have to go to actions tab manually to see the results?

Comment: You'll have to (find an action to) manually attach a check to the commit on the PR, because the trigger `issue_comment` is run in the context of the default branch and not the PR. Also see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72532196/1080523

Comment: Meta question: Thousands of projects on Github have this feature that you can only merge a PR if some checks pass. The only instructions I’ve found for how to set that up are in this SO question with 0 upvotes with an answer based on a repo with 7 stars. It seems to me like there must be another (more canonical) way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this by manually setting the commit status using [@myrotvorets/set-commit-status-action](https://github.com/myrotvorets/set-commit-status-action). The workflow file ended up being like the following

```yaml
name: Testing actions
on:
  issue_comment:
    types: [created, edited]

jobs:
  testing-actions:
    if: github.event.issue.pull_request && contains(github.event.comment.body, '@test')
    name: Just testing
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Get PR details
        uses: xt0rted/pull-request-comment-branch@v1
        id: comment-branch
      - name: Set commit status as pending
        uses: myrotvorets/set-commit-status-action@master
        with:
          sha: ${{ steps.comment-branch.outputs.head_sha }}
          token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          status: pending

      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          ref: ${{ steps.comment-branch.outputs.head_ref }}
      - name: Print stuff
        run: echo "Hello dudes!"

      - name: Set final commit status
        uses: myrotvorets/set-commit-status-action@master
        if: always()
        with:
          sha: ${{ steps.comment-branch.outputs.head_sha }}
          token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          status: ${{ job.status }}
```

This works pretty well, the workflow runs get associated with the PR's head commit, and thus it shows up on the PR page as a check too. Thanks @rethab for the alpha.